# Contact form 7 over the JSON REST API (WP API)?

Tags: json, angularjs, wordpress

is this possible?

To get the `JSON` ([plugin url](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/))  of the `form` (`fields`, `input` types, etc.) how would I have to hook this up in a `plugin`?

Then to use the send mechanism of the `plugin` how would I transfer my rest `POST` to the `plugins` send function?

Any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can hook in the `wpcf7_before_send_mail` action to get POST data right before the mail il sent by CF7.

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'my_wpcf7_choose_recipient');    
function my_wpcf7_choose_recipient($WPCF7_ContactForm)
{
    // use $submission to access POST data
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    $subject = $data['subject']

    // use WPCF7_ContactForm->prop() to access form settings
    $mail = $WPCF7_ContactForm->prop('mail');
    $recipient = $mail['recipient'];

    // update a form property
    $WPCF7_ContactForm->set_properties(array('mail' => $mail));
}
```

Then in this function you can call your plugin and transfer him `$submission`.

And if you want to alter the POST data, you can use the wpcf7_posted_data filter:

```
add_filter('wpcf7_posted_data', 'my_wpcf7_posted_data');
function my_wpcf7_posted_data($data)
{
    $data['subject'] = 'Test ' . $data['subject'];
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is two years old, but I needed the same exact thing so I made a plugin and happened to run across this post.

https://github.com/CodeBradley/contact-form-7-rest-api